# Error trying to share image in assets with third party chat app

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, share-intent

I am trying to get the StreamProvider to share images in my assets/stamps folder, but am doing something wrong. Sorry for asking such a trivial question. Using the demo as an example this is where I am at.

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.np161.stamp2" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Stickers 2"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Stickers 2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".chatHeadPreviewActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="Stickers 2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".ChatHeadService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".newActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Language"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_language" >
    </activity>
</application>

<provider
    android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.np161.stamp2"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>


</manifest>
```

my paths.xml contains this

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <asset name="assets" path="stamps" />
</paths>
```

The activity where I am sending the image

```
assetManager = getResources().getAssets();

    try {
        images = getAssets().list("stamps");
        listImages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(images));
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
```

I use this to populate my gridview and then set the onclick method

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            String path = "assets/" + listImages.get(position);

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getUri(path));

            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            shareIntent.setType("image/png");

            shareIntent.setPackage(ChatHeadService.app);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```

modified getUri method

```
private static final Uri PROVIDER= Uri.parse("content://com.example.np161.stamp2");

private Uri getUri(String pathEnd) {
    String path=pathEnd;

    return(PROVIDER.buildUpon().path(path).build());
}
```

The error i seem to be getting is

```
02-24 10:01:53.280 17563-17610/? E/JHEAD: can't open '/image/png'
02-24 10:01:53.283 17563-17610/? E/JHEAD: can't open '/image/png'
02-24 10:01:53.326 17563-17610/? E/ImageFileManager: Image resize fail
02-24 10:01:53.422 17563-17609/? E/SQLiteLog: (1555) abort at 13 in [INSERT INTO sticker(package_id,sticker_id,order_num,image_width,image_height) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: sticker.sticker_id
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I am still relatively new to android programming

Comment: What is the actual `Uri` that you wound up using, that generated those error messages? It should be something of the form `content://com.example.np161.stamp2/assets/...`, where the `...` part is a relative path into your `assets/` directory of your `app/` module or project.

Comment: @CommonsWare the uri is D/new URI: content://com.example.np161.stamp2/assets/stp_003.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like `app/src/main/assets/stamps/stp_003.png` in your project, that looks fine.

More importantly, it suggests that "can't open '/image/png'" must be pulling from the MIME type. However, the leading slash on that seems like the other app is treating the MIME type as a path, which makes no sense.

You might try sharing with a couple of other apps, to see if they accept your `Uri`, but from the first three lines of that error, it would seem like the problem is on their side, and not in any way that you or I are likely to be able to fix.

Comment: ah the stp_003.png is in a subfolder in the assets folder called stamps.

Comment: @user3074140: No, sorry, that's my fault. I forgot that path segment when writing the answer.

Comment: It seems to work fine with things like facebook messenger and twitter, so its just the Line app which is a problem, unfortunately thats the most important app to share with, but either thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3074140: You may have to go with having the stamps at least temporarily out on external storage and using a `file://` `Uri`. Not all apps are up to snuff with respect to `content://` `Uri` values, particularly if they are not a typical destination for shared content.

Comment: @CommonWare Yes I have tried that but have a strange issue that from my device it shows me sending different images but the receiver just receives the first image sent over and over again.